# Check if Git repo correctly setup

Tags: git

One of our clients has an already existing git repository.

Are there some steps to follow to check if this repository is setup correctly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply start to work with it.

Add files, commit and push them.

- Verify that the central repository is opened to external users
- Verify to see if the user has access to the central repo
- Verify that the user has the required settings: (username,email ssh keys etc)
- Push commits to see if you have the git users has write access to the files

Basically you need to start work on it and verify that all the workflow is working.

Comment: Np. Usually the problems is not with the git setup (using Unix) but the read/write access to files and acess to the machie itself.